# How to break lines at a specific character in Notepad++?

Tags: newline, notepad++, text-editor, line-breaks

I have a text file containing text like:

```
['22APR2012 23:10', '23APR2012 07:10', 1, 3, 0], ['22APR2012 23:10', '23APR2012 07:20', 1, 3, 0], ['22APR2012 23:15', '23APR2012 06:40', 0, 1, 0], ['22APR2012 
23:15', '23APR2012 06:40', 1, 3, 0], ['22APR2012 23:15', '23APR2012 06:40', 0, 1, 0], ['22APR2012 23:15', '23APR2012 07:00', 1, 3, 0], ['22APR2012 23:15', '23APR2012 
07:00', 0, 1, 0], ['22APR2012 23:20', '23APR2012 09:35', 0, 1, 0], ['22APR2012 23:20', '23APR2012 09:35', 1, 3, 0], ['22APR2012 23:20', '23APR2012 10:10', 1, 3, 0], 
['22APR2012 23:25', '23APR2012 05:35', 1, 3, 0],
```

I want the lines break at `],` characters:

```
['22APR2012 19:30', '23APR2012 00:25', 0, 1, 0], 
['22APR2012 19:35', '23APR2012 01:45', 1, 3, 0],
['22APR2012 19:50', '23APR2012 05:25', 1, 3, 0],
['22APR2012 19:50', '23APR2012 05:25', 0, 1, 0],
['22APR2012 19:55', '23APR2012 06:25', 1, 3, 0],
```

Is there a way to do it in Notepad++, or any other editor?

Comment: duplicate of Super user question:http://superuser.com/questions/34451/notepad-find-and-replace-string-with-a-new-line

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this if I want to break it by `;`? The solutions for `]` aren't working for me

Comment: in the accepted solution, just replace '],' with ';'

Answer (score 223, accepted):

1. Click Ctrl + h or Search -> Replace on the top menu
2. Under the Search Mode group, select Regular expression
3. In the Find what text field, type `],\s*`
4. In the Replace with text field, type `],\n`
5. Click Replace All

Comment: To get this to work in Notepad++ version 6.7.8.2 I had to use the Extended Search mode, instead of Regular expression.

Comment: I also had to use Extended, however for a single line break `\n` was only necessary.

Answer (score 38):

> Let's assume `],` is the character where we wanted to break at

1. Open `notePad++`
2. Open `Find window` Ctrl+F
3. Switch to `Replace` Tab
4. Choose `Search Mode` to `Extended`
5. **Type `],` in `Find What` field**
6. **Type `\n`in `Replace with` field**
7. Hit `Replace All`
8. Boom

Comment: 6. Type `\r\n` in `Replace with` field

Comment: To be viewed in Windows (i.e. Notepad) we need \r\n. Otherwise \n works on on any other platform (should break the line and continue below it).

Answer (score 16):

Try this way. It got worked for me

1. Open Notepad++ then copy your content
2. Press `ctrl + h`
3. Find what is should be **,(comma)** or any character that you want to replace
4. Replace with should be **\n**
5. Select Search Mode -> Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0)
6. Then Click on Replace All

Comment: #5 is key.  Really, it's about an extended _replacement_

Answer (score 11):

If the text contains **\r\n** that need to be converted into new lines use the 'Extended' or 'Regular expression' modes and escape the backslash character in 'Find what':

Find what: **\\r\\n**

Replace with: **\r\n**

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how it can work automatically, but you can copy "], " together with new line and then use replace function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to get a comma separated string into a column with CR LF you wont be able to do that in Notepad++, assuming you didn't want to write code, you could manipulate it in Microsoft Excel.

If you copy your string to location B1:

```
A2 =LEFT(B1,FIND(",",B1)-1)
B2 =MID(B1,FIND(",",B1)+1,10000)
```

Select A2 and B2, copy the code to successive cells (by dragging):

```
A3 =LEFT(B2,FIND(",",B2)-1)
B3 =MID(B2,FIND(",",B2)+1,10000)
```

When you get #VALUE! in the last cell of column A replace it with the previous rows B value.

In the end your A column will contain the desired text. Copy and past it anywhere you wish.

Comment: "you wont be able to do that in Notepad++" - that is not true. Use reg exp as creemama exmplained above. It works perfectly.