# Regex to match lines that do NOT have exactly three pipes in a Notepad++ csv

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a pipe-delimited csv. Each row **should** have just three pipes to separate the columns. I need to find any lines that do NOT have three pipes - more OR less should match.

I'm learning regex and I came up with this (kind of hacked together finding parts I thought would work...)

```
^(?:[^|\r\n]*\|){3,}.*$
```

However, it's just matching all rows, regardless of the number of pipes in the row.

What's the correct syntax for what I want to do?

**[UPDATE]**

As @anubhava pointed out, I should provide an example.

This is example data in my file:

```
John Doe|1hgds234|Some comment|
Mary Jane|5df678|This column is the end of this record|Harry Jones|3456|Harry's record should be on the next line|
Sue Anderson|037dsf533|Another comment|
```

Harry Jones' record should start on a new line, starting at "Harry". Each line ends in a pipe and CRLF.

So I need a find/replace with a regex that would match on that second line and put a CRLF after the third pipe in the second line.

Comment: Can you add few samples of valid and invalid matches

Comment: .csv files can have double quotes with pipe characters inside.  Do we need to ignore them (complicates the answer)?

Comment: Replace `^((?:[^\v|]*\|){3})(.+)` with `$1\n$2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't have escaped `|` or `|` inside quoted cell value, uou can match using this regex:

```sh
^((?:[^|\n]*\|){3})(?![\r\n])
```

And replace this with:

$1\n

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jY6rmG/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(?:[^|\n]*\|){3}`:
- `)`: End capture group
- `(?![\r\n])`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have `\r` or `\n` ahead of the current position

Comment: It works! And thanks for the breakdown. Now, why didn't `$1\n` replace the selected text (Mary Jane's entire record was selected) with "$1\n". I'm guessing `1$` is some sort of indicator of the selected text... @Wiktor Stribizew's code worked as well - just a slightly different way - boy, have I got a lot to learn!

Comment: [`\n` should work in replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668044/how-to-break-lines-at-a-specific-character-in-notepad)

Answer (score 1):

The natural thing would be to put a check for 2 pipes plus some data in a positive lookbehind, but Notepad++ doesn't do variable length lookbehind.  Instead we can put the lead-up into a capture group and include that capture group in the result.

```
^(((([^|]*?)|("[^"]*?"))\|){2}([^|]*?|"[^"]*?"))\|(?!$)
```

This allows for quoting between the pipes.  Your replacement string should be $1\n to restore what is captured in group 1.  I took the liberty of allowing a naked pipe character at line end using a negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this short code too, working as expected,
Find what: `^(.*?\K\|){3}(?=.)`
Replace with: `|\n`

Comment: I needed a CRLF, so I added `\r` before the `\n`, but yes , that works as well. Thanks!